# Simple Guess my Number Game in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a javascript program that is a simple guessing game. It comes up with a random number between 1 and 10 and provides an input field and a button for the user to make their guess. The program tells after each guess whether the user guessed too high or too low, and it keeps up with the number of guess it took the user to get the correct answer which it displays along with a "congratulations" message when they get it right.

I'm having some trouble getting it to work properly. The page displays properly, but when I enter a guess and click my submit button, nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Guess My Number</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var game = {
                num : 0,
                turns : 1,
                reset : function() {
                    this.turns = 1;
                    this.newNum();
                },
                newNum() : function() {
                    this.num = parseInt(Math.random() * 10) +1;
                },
                checkNum() : function(guess) {
                    try {
                        guess = parseInt(guess);
                    }
                    catch(e) {
                        alert("Enter a guess!");
                        this.turns++;
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (guess == this.num) {
                        alert("Correct! It took you " + this.turns + "turns to guess my number.");
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if(guess > this.num) {
                        alert("Your guess is too high. Try again.");
                        this.turns++;
                        return false;
                    }
                    else (guess < this.num) {
                        alert("Your guess is too low. Try again.");
                        this.turns++;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            };

            function guessNumber() {
                var guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
                game.checkGuess(guess);
            }

            function resetGame() {
                game.reset();
            }

            resetGame();
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Would You Like To Play A Game?</h1>
        <h2>Thank you for checking out my game. Good luck!</h2>
        <h3>Created by Beth Tanner</h3>
        <h2>Directions:</h2>
        <p>
            The game is very simple. I am thinking of a number between 1
            and 10. It is your job to guess that number. If you do not guess
            correctly on your first attempt, don't worry, you can keep guessing 
            until you guess the correct number.
        </p>
        <p>
        Your Guess: <input type="text" id="guess" size="10" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Sumbit Guess" onclick="guessNumber()" />
        <input type="button" value="Reset Game" onclick="resetGame()" />
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've never actually worked with Javascript before so I know this is probably a very basic thing that I'm overlooking. Any ideas as to why this isn't working correctly?

Comment: `var tunrs = 0;` should be `var turns = 0;`

Comment: As @Musa mentioned fix that, & initialize to some value, it is not going in any `if` condition.

Comment: Where do you set `guess`? You have nothing in your script that says to run your function when clicking the Submit button.

Comment: Your instructions say that you're thinking of a non-decimal number. But `Math.random() * 10` will return a number with a fraction. Where do you remove the fraction? I don't think it's fair to expect the player to guess all those decimal digits. :)

Comment: That's one of the things I'm wondering about @Barmar, I don't know how to do that.  And thanks for pointing out my typo guys, I guess I've gotten too used to automatic spell check.

Comment: Ah ok, one of the examples I saw online had it written like Math.random() *100 and they were trying to find a number between 1 and 100, so figured mine would be *10.

Comment: Don't you think you should learn how to do the basic things when you're writing the program? Did you just expect it to work magically? If you have a Javascript textbook, I'm sure it explains how to run a function when clicking on a button.

Comment: That example probably didn't want an integer, it just wanted any number from 0 to 100. If you want an integer, you need to use a function like `Math.floor()` to remove the fraction.

Comment: You are using a submit button but I don't see any form! and bdw how is your guessnumber() function being called??

Comment: @Nivedita There's no need for a form. This application is entirely in the browser, it's not sending a form to the server.

Comment: and how is the function being called? @Barmar

Comment: To run the function when clicking on the button, you can either use the `onclick` attribute in the submit button, or use the `addEventListener` method in Javascript.

Comment: IMO using input type="button" should be more convenient.

Comment: @Nivedita I already asked that in my first comment. He answered that he doesn't know how to do that.

Comment: If there's no form, there's essentially no difference between `type=button` and `type=submit`. They both just display a button.

Comment: Ok, I've done a little more googling and have added the onclick attribute to my submit button. Still playing around with it to get it to work though.

Comment: Can you update your code in the question? @BethTanner

Comment: I updated the question with my current code. As this is written though, nothing is happening when I press the submit button, but I get the alerts when I reload the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several other answers have pointed out some issues in the test code:

- `type="submit"` but no `<form>` tags.
- Misspelled variable name `tunrs` instead of `turns`.
- Use of the `while` loop
- No event connections between the buttons and the JavaScript

This is a simple code example, and there are so, SO many ways to tackle it in JavaScript. Here is my method.

When creating a simple game board where the page does not need to be reloaded, I like to create a `game` object. In JavaScript you can create objects in a variety of ways. But one of the simplest is this:

```
var game = {};
```

This creates an empty object with no properties or methods. To create a couple of properties:

```
var game = {
    num: 0,
    turns: -1
};
```

Each of these properties can be referenced globally like `var x = game.num;`. To create the object with a function:

```
var game = {
    num: 0,
    turns: 0,
    reset: function() {
        this.turns = 0;
        //get a random integer between 1 and 10
        this.num = parseInt(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        //Note: "this" lets you refer to the current object context. "game" in this case.
        //There are a couple of ways to force the value to an Int, I chose parseInt
    }
};
```

Game now has a `game.reset()` function that will set `game.turns` back to 0 and get a new `game.num`. Here is the full javascript code for my example (slightly different than the above examples):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Create an object to hold the game info
    var game = {
        num : 0,
        turns : 0,
        reset : function() {
            //function to reset 
            this.turns = 0;
            this.newNum();
        },
        newNum : function() {
            //get a random integer between 1 and 10
            this.num = parseInt(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        },
        checkGuess : function(guess) {
            //try to convert the guess into a integer
            try {
                guess = parseInt(guess);
            } catch(e) {
                alert("Enter a guess!");
                this.turns++;
                return false;
            }

            //perform strict check of equality
            if (guess === this.num) {
                alert("Correct! It took you " + this.turns + " turn(s) to guess my number");
                return true;
            } else if (guess > this.num) {
                alert("Your guess is too high. Try again.");
                this.turns++;
                return false;
            } else {
                alert("Your guess is too low. Try again.");
                this.turns++;
                return false;
            }
        }
    };


    function guessNumber() {
        var guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
        game.checkGuess(guess);
    }

    function resetGame() {
        game.reset();
    }

    resetGame();
</script>
```

Note: I didn't do a `window.onload` event here because those are only needed when the code will be interacting with elements on the document, or DOM elements. If you try to execute JS code in the `head` of the document, it gets executed instantly before the rest of the document gets loaded. This is bad if your JS code is trying to get, set, or manipulate elements in the page because you're still in the `head` and the `body` hasn't been loaded yet.

So in the case where your code needs to get access to elements of the page, often a `window.onload = someInitFunction();` will be used so that the JS code will be executed after the document has completed it's load.

Below is my HTML code. It is mostly similar to your code except that I change the `name` attribute to `id` on the "guess" input to make it easier to access with `document.getElementById()`. Using `name` is helpful when you are in a `form` and will be submitting values to a server. Only fields with the `name` attribute set get submitted in that case. Often on forms you will have something like `<input type="text" id="textfield" name="textfield" />`. The `id` is used in JavaScript for easy of access, and `name` is used when submitting the form back to the server.

I also added `onclick` attributes to the buttons, and changed the `input type="submit"` to `input type="button"`.

```
<h1>Would You Like To Play A Game?</h2>
<h2>Thank you for checking out my game. Good luck!</h2>
<h3>Created by Beth Tanner</h3>
<h2>Instructions</h2>
<p>
    The game is very simple, I am thinking of a non-decimal number between 1 and 10
    and it is your job to guess what that number is. If you do not guess my number 
    correctly on your first attempt, that's ok, you can keep guessing until you are correct.
</p>
<p>
    Your guess:<input type="text" id="guess" size = "10" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" value = "Submit Guess" onclick="guessNumber()" />
    <input type="button" value = "Reset Game" onclick="resetGame()" />
</p>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0n1k91yw/) example that operates, I believe, the way you want it to.

**update**
As I was saying there are so many ways to do this. [Here is an alternate way to give number selections](http://jsfiddle.net/0n1k91yw/1/).

Comment: For some reason when I implement this in my own code the buttons still aren't working properly. I can click either button and nothing happens.

Comment: Double check the `onclick` attributes on the buttons, and check the JavaScript functions in my example. Below the `game` object code there are a couple of functions.

Comment: I updated my most recent code. I don't see anything wrong when I look through it, but I could definitely be missing something.

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if there were any JavaScript errors?

Comment: I'm getting the following errors: SyntaxError: missing : after property id project2.html:13 (but the : is there, so not sure what's going on), The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol, and ReferenceError: guessNumber is not defined

Comment: There should be a comma after `turns:1`

Comment: I actually added that comma right before I opened the console to check for errors. I added it to the code in my original question.

Comment: Remove the parenthesis after newNum() and checkNum() in the game object.

Comment: That got rid of one error, still getting the character encoding error, and am now getting a new error that says that game.checkGuess isn't a function.

Comment: The checkGuess means that you're trying to call a function that doesn't exist. I think you should be able to find that one pretty easy. Just follow the code path starting at the button onclick. There is a name discrepancy.

Comment: On the encoding error, you may have picked up a stray Unicode character during your copy and paste. It happens, and can be a pain to find. You might have to paste the code over into a notepad, then paste it back and see if that works. Sometimes that will cause weird non-printing characters to drop out. If that didn't work, you might have to clear the code and retype it by hand.

Comment: @BethTanner were you able to find the function name discrepancy or fix the encoding problem?

Comment: Sorry, I've been kind of multitasking going between this and another assignment I'm working on for another class. I have fixed the function name error, but will have to look more into the encoding error tomorrow. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Corrected the encoding error, I had failed to include the meta tag in my header. It works perfectly now. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

You variable `guess` is undefined.

Just initialize it with :

```
var guess = 0;
```

However be careful there's a possibility that `num` is initialize to 0. So, the user guessed immediatly without doing nothing.

```
var num = Math.random() *10 + 1;
```

BR

Answer (score 1):

You should call your function in first place, one possible thing you can do is:

```
<input type = "button" value = "Submit Guess" onclick="guessNumber()">
```

now that your function is called you need to get the value entered by the user into your `guess` variable, which I don't see in your code, you can do it as:

```
Your guess:<input type = "text" name = "guess" size = "10" id="guess" /> <br />
```

and then in your java script initialize the variable `guess` as:

```
guess=document.getElementById("guess").value;
```

This should do the thing!

**EDIT:**
Also make sure that `Math.random()` returns an Integer,as others have suggested use `Math.ceil()` !

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with your code:

1. `Math.random()*10` will return something that looks like `8.523525235`, so you'll have a hard time matching that to any guesses. Instead, use `Math.ceil(Math.random()*10)`. This generates a random number and then rounds up to the nearest integer.
2. In your JavaScript code, you're calling `guessNumber()` on the last line, which will execute the function as soon as the browser gets to that line. This will mean the function being executed before the user puts in any guesses. Instead you need to attach an event listener to the button, so that when the button is clicked, `guessNumber()` is called. Something like:

`document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', guessNumber)`.

3. Right now you're not setting the variable `guess` in any way. You need to grab the value of the text box and assign that to `guess`. Something like:

`guess = document.getElementById('textbox').value`

4. Using a `while` loop is not appropriate here, since the user is using the textbox and the button to submit guesses each time. There are ways of doing this with a `while` loop, but let's stick with your current setup.

You want something that resembles this:

HTML:

```
<p>Your guess:
    <input type="text" id="textbox" />
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Guess" />
</p>
```

JS:

```
var rand = Math.ceil(Math.random()*10);
var turns = 0;
var guess;

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', guess);

function guess() {
    guess = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
    if (guess == rand) {
        alert('Correct! It took you ' + turns + ' turns to guess the number!');
    } else if (guess < rand) {
        alert('Your guess is too low. Try again.');
        turns++;
    } else if (guess > rand) {
        alert('Your guess is too high. Try again.');
        turns++;
    } else {
        alert('You didn\'t enter a number. Try again.');
    }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q1ffmywf/1/). I added some for the reset functionality.

Comment: This is very helpful, however, when I click the Guess button, nothing happens.

Comment: @BethTanner That's odd, the fiddle works for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: The fiddle works for me too, but when I try it in my own code, the buttons still don't work. I figured I must've typed something incorrectly, but even tried copying and pasting this into notepad with the same result. I'm using Firefox, but have also tried it on Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Comment: @BethTanner Make sure all the id names are correct. Also, are you putting this code inside any other function or anything like that?